# RJDBC returning table names but not the content with Athena

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect Athena to R and fetch data from it.
Here are the different steps I did :

```
  library(rJava)

    URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.1.jar'    


    fil <- basename(URL)


    if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil,mode = "wb")  


    library(dplyr)  

    library(RJDBC)  

    drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver",  
 fil, identifier.quote="'")     

    con <-  dbConnect(drv, 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:443/',                                     s3_staging_dir="s3://my-s3",user="ACCESS_KEY",password="SECRET_KEY")



    dbListTables(con). 



    dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM sampledb.elb_logs")
```

dbListTables(con)  gives me a the needed output (name of the tables )  :

```
[1] "elb_logs"
```

but the dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM sampledb.elb_logs") gives an error :

```
    Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
      Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM sampledb.elb_logs (Failed to  
 run query)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try https://github.com/hrbrmstr/metis or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AWR.Athena/

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an interesting issue.

Quick question:

Did you connect to the same region where your result set location is located?  Is `s3://my-s3` in `eu-west-2`?

I was doing some hacking and was able to reproduce your error with the following code, wherein my bucket is in `us-west-2`, but I specify and Athena endpoint in `us-east-1`.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

driver_path <- '/drivers/jdbc/athena/1.1.0/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar'
driver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", driver_path, identifier.quote="'")

con <- jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(driver, 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/',
                               s3_staging_dir="s3://***-west",
                               user = '**********',
                               password = '**********')
# Connect to Athena specifying us-east-1 and a staging directory in us-west-2

dbListTables(con)

# Gives me the tables in my Athena catalog

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT now()")

# Throws the following error
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT now() (Failed to run query)
```

From a new R session, I then reconnected to Athena through `us-east-1` and specify a bucket to hold output hosted in `us-east-1`.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

driver_path <- '/drivers/jdbc/athena/1.1.0/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar'
driver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", driver_path, identifier.quote="'")

con <- jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(driver, 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/',
                               s3_staging_dir="s3://***-east",
                               user = '**********',
                               password = '**********')

dbListTables(con)

# Lists the tables in my Athena catalog

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT now()")

# Returns
# _col0
# 2017-11-08 21:16:26.496 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer ! So after trying the same code on Python and Java, I found out that the issue was related to the driver. the one I was using was apparently outdated. I installed the last driver, restarted Rstudio, now works perfectly ! Thanks !